# Why does the table rows increment on component re-render?

Tags: html, reactjs, typescript, html-table, logic

I created a component that accepts a label and an array and then returns a table for displaying the data that was passed. But for some reason, whenever the component re-renders, the table rows increments because the data repeats and displays it again below the table. Here's my code...

```
import React from 'react';

interface Props {
  labels: any[];
  data: any[];
}

const sampleData = [
  {
    rowLabel: 'Fever',
    key: 'key',
    value: 'value',
  },
  {
    rowLabel: 'Colds',
    key: 'key',
    value: 'value',
  },
];

const Display: React.FC<Props> = ({ labels, data }: Props) => {
  return (
    <>
      <table
        style={{
          direction: 'ltr',
          width: '100%',
          flexDirection: 'row',
        }}
      >
        {labels.map((label, index) => (
          <tr key={index} style={{ border: '2px solid #e8e8e9' }}>
            <td style={{ border: '2px solid #e8e8e9', textAlign: 'center' }}>
              {label}
            </td>
            {data.map((data) => {
              return data.rowLabel === label ? (
                <tr
                  key={index}
                  style={{
                    display: 'flex',
                    flexDirection: 'row',
                    borderInline: '1px solid #e8e8e9',
                    borderBottom: '1px solid #e8e8e9',
                    paddingLeft: '5px',
                  }}
                >
                  <td
                    style={{
                      width: '50%',
                      textOverflow: 'ellipsis',
                    }}
                  >
                    {data.key}
                  </td>
                  <td
                    style={{
                      borderLeft: '2px solid #e8e8e9',
                      width: '50%',
                      textAlign: 'right',
                      paddingRight: '5px',
                    }}
                  >
                    {data.value}
                  </td>
                </tr>
              ) : null;
            })}
          </tr>
        ))}
      </table>
    </>
  );
};

export default Display;
```

And here is me calling the component

```
<Display
 labels={['Fever','Colds']}
 data={sampleData}
/>
```

Im still a noob and any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: In your inner loop it looks like you'll have key collisions since it's useing the outer loop's `index` as its key

Comment: That worked perfect @Nick, thanks! I wish I knew more about this key collision thing though